# How to increase APFS volume size

Tags: macos, partition, apfs

I used to have 160 GB macOS APFS container and I upgraded my laptop's SSD with a bigger one and I wanted to increase the size of APFS container to 260 GB. I created an APFS partition and copied old APFS volume to new one with dd command. See the attached picture for the result. APFS container is 260 GB but APFS volumes are still 160 GB. As far as I know only APFS containers can be resized, so how can I match APFS volumes size with the container size (260 GB)?

[image]

Comment: The OP has already stated in the OP's answer that this is an identical problem with an identical solution. See: [APFS Container Disk & APFS Container Scheme Mismatch - Cannot Resize](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360686/apfs-container-disk-apfs-container-scheme-mismatch-cannot-resize)

Comment: Yes. I added this as answer.

Comment: When you find a question/answer which solves your problem, then you can [elect to up vote](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) the question and/or answer. I believe posting another question followed by a duplicate answer is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution from another post: [APFS Container Disk & APFS Container Scheme Mismatch - Cannot Resize](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360686/apfs-container-disk-apfs-container-scheme-mismatch-cannot-resize)

I need to resize the container to smaller to fix the mismatch and then resize with 0 like this:

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s6 200g
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s6 0
```